# Why was this flag on a spam comment declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging, spam

I recently found this comment below [a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119243/how-to-design-a-2d-chess-board-in-unity):

> It sounds like you might want to complete more of your course before taking off on your own. Check out my profile if you'd like a free trial for a training site, they have a few nice courses for people getting started with Unity, and when you're ready, you can take my advanced course :)

This is obviously not an attempt to improve the question or get it answered. It is solely an attempt to get someone to subscribe to a paid service provided by another website. The link in the author's profile seems to include an affiliate-ID which makes me believe that they get some form of incentive for advertising this website.

So I flagged the comment as "other..." and in the free-text description I described it as spam and referenced our ["how to not be a spammer"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) guide.

But to my surprise, the flag was declined and the comment was not deleted.

Why?

Answer (score 4):

- The author's disclosure of affiliation is extremely clear.
- The author's activity in other comments and answers clearly demonstrates that referencing his course is a minority aspect of his participation.
- The overwhelming majority of the other answers posted by the author have nothing to do with the course and clearly indicate solutions to problems, et cetera.

I don't think the comment in question fits the metrics appropriate for flagging it as spam. It *is* permissible to refer people to software or other off-site resources you-the-poster have some affiliation with, after all.

Comment: Always the voice of reason.